# More of an efficient way to write this?

Tags: c

I'm reading a book on C, and the question it asks me to do is:

> Write a program that uses printf to display the following picture on the screen

and then it's a checkmark with asteriks. So the first thing that came to mind was write a bunch of printf() statements that use the format width specifier. So I came out with this:

```
int main() {
    printf("This program prints a checkmark using asteriks\n"); 

    char asterik = '*';


    printf("%10c\n", asterik);
    printf("%9c\n", asterik);
    printf("%8c\n", asterik);
    printf("%7c\n", asterik);
    printf("%6c\n", asterik);
    printf("%c %3c\n", asterik, asterik);
    printf("%2c %c\n", asterik, asterik);
    printf("%3c\n", asterik);

    return 0;

}
```

I know this code is hideous, disgusting all the 9 yards, but I'm really wondering if there is a more efficient and cleaner looking way? I'm not sure if the author intended it to be written like this, considering this lesson is asked in Chapter 2, where we just went over some very basic things, none pertaining to this. (I only remember how to adjust the width thanks to K&R)

Comment: Probably a silly question but the author doesn't offer his/her own solution? Not even in the back of the book?

Comment: @DigitalNinja Not that I've seen, I may have scrolled past it perhaps! I'd imagine the author would, as it'd be stupid not to :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be nicer to just have a single string literal, as in:

```
const char checkmark[] =
    "       *\n"
    "      * \n"
    "     *  \n"
    "*   *   \n"
    " * *    \n"
    "  *     \n"
    ;

printf("%s", checkmark);
```

Comment: I've never felt so stupid in my entire life. Thanks for the response!

Comment: 100% agree with this answer. When it comes to **maintaining** code that does formatted output to the console, absolute string literals are the best compared to fancy loops and condensed code.

Comment: You might as well use `puts()`

Comment: @chqrlie Probably not a good idea given that the task is to `Write a program that uses printf`.

Comment: Oops! you have to use printf... I wonder if arrays have been covered yet. If not, use the nicely aligned array initalizer directly as an argument to `printf`. A clever compiler will generate a call to `puts()` with a different string literal.  At least `gcc` does.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if arrays and loops were already covered, but in case they were then you could just translate it into an array of formats (e.g. `char *formats[] = { "%10c\n", "%9c\n", ... }`), and then loop over these formats and print the asterisk:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_of_formats; i++)
{
    printf(formats[i], asterisk);
}
```

Note that in this case you'll have to treat lines with two asterisks as having two formats. I.e. instead of using `"%c %3c\n"`, you'll define the following two formats `"%c "` and `"%3c\n"`

Comment: Arrays and loops haven't been covered yet :)